# Metal: Sampling texture is faster than load threadgroup memory?

Tags: graphics, shader, metal, compute-shader, threadgroup

I wrote the following **compute shader** to blur images with some complex kernel:

```cpp
// use Packhalf5 to align to 16 B
struct Packhalf5
{
    half4 a;
    half4 b;
};

kernel void cs_main(
texture2d_array<float> t_f123 [[texture(0)]]
, texture2d_array<float, access::write> t_normal [[texture(3)]]
, sampler s_f123 [[sampler(0)]]
, uint3 gl_GlobalInvocationID [[thread_position_in_grid]]
, uint3 gl_LocalInvocationID [[thread_position_in_threadgroup]]
)
{
    // use Packhalf5 to align to 16 B
    // BLOCK_SIZE_Y = 1
    // BLOCK_SIZE_X = 128 or 64 or 32
    // MAX_PIXR = 20
    threadgroup Packhalf5 gCache[BLOCK_SIZE_Y][BLOCK_SIZE_X + 2 * MAX_PIXR];
    
    // cache texture samples in thread group memory gCache so that we can read it quickly and avoid most texture samples in loop
    if (gl_LocalInvocationID.y < _35)
    {
       // ...
        Packhalf5 pkh5;
        pkh5.a.xyz = half3(half4(t_f123.sample(s_f123, _2.xy, uint(round(_2.z)), level(0.0))).xyz);
        pkh5.b.xy = half2(half4(t_f45.sample(s_f45, _2.xy, uint(round(_2.z)), level(0.0))).xy);
        gCache[gl_LocalInvocationID.x][gl_LocalInvocationID.y] = pkh5;
    }
    if (gl_LocalInvocationID.y >= uint(BLOCK_SIZE_X - _34))
    {
        // ...
        Packhalf5 pkh5;
        pkh5.a.xyz = half3(half4(t_f123.sample(s_f123, _3.xy, uint(round(_3.z)), level(0.0))).xyz);
        pkh5.b.xy = half2(half4(t_f45.sample(s_f45, _3.xy, uint(round(_3.z)), level(0.0))).xy);
        gCache[gl_LocalInvocationID.x][_36] = pkh5;
    }

    Packhalf5 pkh5;
    pkh5.a.xyz = half3(half4(t_f123.sample(s_f123, _31.xy, uint(round(_31.z)), level(0.0))).xyz);
    pkh5.b.xy = half2(half4(t_f45.sample(s_f45, _31.xy, uint(round(_31.z)), level(0.0))).xy);
    gCache[gl_LocalInvocationID.x][_37] = pkh5;

    threadgroup_barrier(mem_flags::mem_threadgroup);

    // use gCache to blur image
    for (int i = 0;i<kernel_size;++i)
    {
        // calculate index
        int a = f1(i);
        int b = f2(i);
        Packhalf5 pkh5;
        //it is extremly slow than directly sampling texture (t_f123.sample(s_f123, _3.xy, uint(round(_3.z)), level(0.0))
        pkh5 = gCache[gl_LocalInvocationID.x][a];
        float2 _42 = float2(pkh5.b.xy);
        float3 _43 = (float3(pkh5.a.xyz) * float3(1.0, 0.5, 0.5)) + float3(0.0, -0.25, -0.25);
        //it is extremly slow than directly sampling texture
        pkh5 = gCache[gl_LocalInvocationID.x][b];
        float2 _45 = float2(pkh5.b.xy);
        float3 _46 = (float3(pkh5.a.xyz) * float3(1.0, 0.5, 0.5)) + float3(0.0, -0.25, -0.25);
        // use _42,_43,_45_46
    }
    // wirte blur result
    t_normal.write(_16, uint2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy), uint(gl_GlobalInvocationID.z));
}
```

I wrote this shader to optimize some blur operations which is similar to Gaussian Blur on a **128x128 picture**, and I test and profile it on **iPhone XR** in the Xcode frame debugger found that :

the loading from thread group memory "gCache" in the loop is **so slow** than directly sample texture (ie. `t_f123.sample(s_f123, _3.xy, uint(round(_3.z)), level(0.0)`)
(*Shader take **30%** of total time to load gCache, but take only **< 5%** of the total time if I change to directly sample texture to sample texture* )

As for the performance counter,  the texture reading is actually going down but things strange is that the main memory bandwidth is nearly not changed.

I guess that there is a data hazard because that the use of too much thread group memory?